# How to make Qt Creator add CEF framework to DEST_DIR on Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmake, chromium-embedded

I'm working on a collaborative project in Qt Creator, and I've managed to get it to compile: I linked CEF Framework and the CEF dll wrapper. However, when I try to run it I get:

> ```
> dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/Chromium Embedded Framework
> Reason: image not found
> ```

As far as my understanding goes, the framework needs to be copied into my DEST_DIR, into .app/Contents/MacOS or something like that. I have NOT managed to make it work even by copying the framework there manually.
Also, since the development is meant to be cross platform, I was wondering if there's a way to tell qmake how to copy the framework to my DEST_DIR. 
Any help in understanding how to deal with frameworks on Mac OS X in Qt Creator would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure, is there some reason you can't use QtWebEngine? It's based on Chromium Embedded Framework and is already built in to Qt.

Comment: I'm not in charge of the decision to use CEF, using some code from older projects is the reason for going with CEF. UPD: Also, I heard something about the engine not supporting Drag&Drop yet and in the *very* near future, I might be mistaking though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as my understanding goes, the framework needs to be copied into my DEST_DIR, into .app/Contents/MacOS or something like that.

You're nearly there. Frameworks are generally copied into

> .app/Contents/Frameworks

However, your bundle's executable contains a reference to where it expects those framework libraries are residing and having copied them into the app bundle, you need to tell the executable where they are.

Using **oTool** with **-L** argument, [you can see the libraries referenced by the executable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#additional-libraries). You'd call it with the full path. For example

```
otool -L /Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator
```

For each dylib in the framework, you need to fix up the path using the command line tool **install_name_tool**

When [deploying a Qt application](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html) for Qt, we must run the **macdeployqt**. This essentially does the same thing for the Qt Frameworks; copies them into the relevant Frameworks folder and updates the paths.

I've not used it myself, but according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#the-mac-deployment-tool), macdeployqt supports handling 3rd party frameworks, with the option *-executable=< path >*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up writing a script and adding it into my .pro file so that qmake would run it after linking, coldn't find any other way to actually test/run the app.